# PHP table rows based on table header

Tags: php

i want to create a table of all classes as table header and rows with name of student in each class each column according to it header, all data come from two (students, classes) mx code :

```
<table>
    <thead >
<?php 
     foreach ($groupList as $group):
?>
      
     <th><?= $group['group_name'] ?></th>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</thead>
<tbody>
     <tr>
     <?php 
          foreach ($groupList as $group) {
              echo '<td>' ;
              foreach ($db->getStudentsByGroup($group['u_id']) as $name){
                 echo  $name['fname'] ;
              }
              echo '</td>';
          }
     ?>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

this code shows them grouped as wanted but all names are in the same row as below

```
group1            group2
tom, sam, bob,    x, y ,...
mark, ...
```

, i tried to change the location of the (td, tr) but no success, any idea how to do it properly , thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If i m not wrong this should do the trick!

my array:

```
$array = array(
    'group1' => array(
        'aaa',
        'bbb',
        'ccc'
    ),
    'group2' => array(
        'ddd',
        'eee',
        'fff'
    )   
);
```

Working code:

```
echo '
<table border="1">
    <thead>';
        
        foreach($array AS $tname => $tvalue){
            echo '<th>'.$tname.'</th>';
        }

    echo '
    </thead>
    <tbody>';

        $keys = array_keys($array);
        $first_key = $keys[0];
        foreach ($array[$first_key] as $id => $value) {
            $body .= "<tr>";
            foreach ($keys as $k) {
                $body .= "<td>" . $array[$k][$id] . "</td>";
            }
            $body .= "</tr>";
        }
        echo $body;

    echo '
    </tbody>
</table>';
```

Comment: i tried that also then all name are in one row each in one cell

Comment: You need to be more specific of how your data are stored and how you want to show them

Comment: i have table for groups and table for students each student can be only in one group but each group contain many student , i want to generate a table in table header display groups name and in table body display student name in each column the students according to column header (according to the group the are in)

Comment: If you want each name to be in new line (`<tr>`) then also `<tr>` need to be inside loop

Comment: i also tried to put the tr in the loop but then each name is a row but in all the name are in the same column.

Comment: @george try my edit (you prob need to modify some thing)